# How to specify root node of tree for UI Automation tree

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, automation

I saw some sample code for parsing the UI Automation tree using VB.NET.  The code is here:

```
'' <summary> 
''' Walks the UI Automation tree and adds the control type of each element it finds  
''' in the control view to a TreeView. 
''' </summary> 
''' <param name="rootElement">The root of the search on this iteration.</param> 
''' <param name="treeNode">The node in the TreeView for this iteration.</param> 
''' <remarks> 
''' This is a recursive function that maps out the structure of the subtree beginning at the 
''' UI Automation element passed in as rootElement on the first call. This could be, for example, 
''' an application window. 
''' CAUTION: Do not pass in AutomationElement.RootElement. Attempting to map out the entire subtree of 
''' the desktop could take a very long time and even lead to a stack overflow. 
''' </remarks> 

Private Sub WalkControlElements(ByVal rootElement As AutomationElement, ByVal treeNode As TreeNode)
    ' Conditions for the basic views of the subtree (content, control, and raw)  
    ' are available as fields of TreeWalker, and one of these is used in the  
    ' following code. 

    Dim elementNode As AutomationElement = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetFirstChild(rootElement)

    While (elementNode IsNot Nothing)
        Dim childTreeNode As TreeNode = treeNode.Nodes.Add(elementNode.Current.ControlType.LocalizedControlType)
        WalkControlElements(elementNode, childTreeNode)
        elementNode = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetNextSibling(elementNode)
    End While 

End Sub 'WalkControlElements
```

If I want to use this, I have to pass in the rootElement.  I'm wondering what the syntax for this is?  Using UISpy, I can see the class name is "WindowsForm10.Window.8.app.0.378734a".

Answer (score 0):

`AutomationElement.RootElement` would give you the root of the AutomationElement tree, which is the desktop. If you want to get a different element, you can create a `Condition` object then call `AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst` or `AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll`, depending on what you want to do here.